# json ajax php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax

I have table users.

- id
- login
- password

I want to display the data in JSON format through php mysql

page: config.php

```
$rep = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
$array_user = array();
while($data =  $rep->fetch()){
    $array_user = $data;
}
echo json_encode($array_user);
?>
```

page listUsers.php

```
<div  id="tab"></div>

<script>
    $(document).on("ready",function(){

        loadData();
    });
    var loadData = function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
             url:"config.php"
        }).done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var users = JSON.parse(data);


            for(var i in users){
                $("#tab").append(users[i].login + "<br>");
            }

        });
    }
</script>
```

but it appears to me **"undefined"**.

Comment: Use it as `$array_user[] = $data;`

Comment: what is the output you are getting?
    $array_user = $data;
 Instead, try something like, 
    array_push($array_user, $data);

Comment: If you add datatype: 'json' into your $.ajax parameters, you can remove your JSON.parse in "done" event, getting var users = data; instead. Furthermore, use "success" and "error" events instead of "done" to determine if it ended well or not (more here : http://api.jquery.com/Ajax_Events/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use this**

```
<?php 

$rep = $db->query("SELECT * FROM users");
$array_user = array();
while($data =  $rep->fetch()){
    $array_user[] = $data;
}
echo json_encode($array_user);

?>


<div  id="tab"></div>

<script>
    $(document).on("ready",function(){

        loadData();
    });
    var loadData = function(){
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
             url:"config.php"
        }).done(function(data){
            console.log(data);
            var users = JSON.parse(data);


            for(var i in users){
                $("#tab").append(users[i].login + "<br>");
            }

        });
    }
</script>
```